# What are "dynamic constraints" in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently trying to write an assignment which requires me to incorporate a dynamic constraint, but I have no idea what it is!

Please help, I'm so lost!

Comment: Did you google it? What have you tried? What were the results?

Comment: It's not a standard term.  You'll have to check with you instructor to see what they meant by it.

Comment: Yeah i looked everywhere i could online, but all i could get were scholarly articles that i can't fully read because it won't let me download them. The closest thing i got for an answer is, "Static integrity constraints are semantic properties that are invariant across evolving database states. Dynamic integrity constraints refer explicitly to several (mostly consecutive) states or to their transitions, typically involving temporal or procedural constructs." This doesn't really make much sense to me though..